# Navigating to a new view in iOS

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitableview, navigation

In my iPad application I added `UISearchBar` programmatically. 
When I click on the searchBar, a table containing data appears. When I tap on the row in table, it should navigate to new view

for example:

[image: this is my screenshot]

when I tap on "reliance" it should show a new view. Any suggestions on how I can accomplish this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath        {
     ContentController *detailview = [[ContentController alloc]            initWithNibName:@"ContentController" bundle:nil];    
      detailview.detailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];    

    [self.view addSubView:detailView];
     [detailview release];
   }
```

so I added the code above. Do I need to do anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement the `UITableViewDelegate` method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` and push your new view onto the navigation stack.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
// Some code 
// Initialize your new view here
[self.navigationController pushViewContoller:yourViewController animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: do i need to drag any thing in my .xib ?

Comment: You dont need to drag anything but if you want you can drag the delegate of your tableview to your FilesOwner. Just make sure your class implements the `UITableViewDelegate` and then in your code add this `yourTableView.delegate = self;`

Comment: do i need to add viewController file by going file -> new file -> under cocoa Touch -> UIViewControllerSubclass ..

Answer (score 0):

Try -

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath        {
     ContentController *detailview = [[ContentController alloc]            initWithNibName:@"ContentController" bundle:nil];    
      detailview.detailString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
   //  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailview animated:YES];     

    [self.view addSubView:detailView];
     [detailview release];
   }
```

Comment: do i need to write any thing else ?

Comment: what is detailview in this ? is it my new view when i click reliance ? how should i map my old view with new view ?

Comment: if you want new view then you do addSubView rather than pushViewController ,

Comment: do i need to add viewController file by going file -> new file -> under cocoa Touch -> UIViewControllerSubclass ..

Comment: it shows error replace ContentController with UIMenuController

Comment: first tell me after adding this code.. to my project do i need to do anything ?

Comment: @DipakChaudhari Adding detailView as a subView and releasing it will lead to exceptions if there are events like button press etc in the detailView.